# www doesn't work with heroku app, other subdomains do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, subdomain

I have a Ruby on Rails heroku app that I am trying to use with my HostGator hosted domain.

I've edited the CNAME records and can make any subdomain work, EXCEPT www

Example:

- ww2.site.com - works fine
- crap.site.com - works fine
- www.site.com - does not work
- site.com - does not work

Why can I only use subdomains that aren't www?

Comment: How did you edit the CNAME records? Also site.com isn't working and not a subdomain, is that what you want?

Comment: I edited the CNAME records in HostGator's 'Advanced DNS Zone Editor' tool entering the subdomain as the Name, default TTL of 14400, Type: CNAME, and then the heroku app address (herokuappname.herokuapp.com). Regarding site.com not working, I just put that in because I'd be fine with that working if it was the only way. I just don't understand why www does not work

Comment: I did this for a new domain last week.  I followed the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains. Basically just forward the naked domain to www. Add a cname entry for www.  I was on godaddy instead of hostgator but should be able to do it there.

Comment: The www subdomain started working eventually - for some reason it didn't propagate instantly like other subdomains but now it works. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This only speaks on the naked domain (example.com) you mentioned above.

Heroku does not [support naked domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain) (using conventional DNS A-records), however there are a few ways to get around that.

(1). The best solution is to buy an SSL certificate for your site. You would have to buy the [Add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/SSL) from Heroku, then also buy the actual certificate from a third-party. However, this is not as easy at buying the certificate and voila!

(2). This [way, using wwwizer](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect), which is the easiest way to do this, works but has exceptions where it might not. To use this, point your "naked domain" (example.com not www.example.com!) to IP address 174.129.25.170